# Delete multiple rows in Codeigniter by multiple columns

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an associative array, like:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "10"
    ["customerId"]=>
    string(3) "1809"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "13"
    ["customerId"]=>
    string(3) "1094"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "45"
    ["customerId"]=>
    string(2) "210"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to delete these rows from database, but I can't find correct Codeigniter' query to run.

The generated query should be like this:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE (userId,customer_id) IN ( (10,1809),(10,1809),(45,210) )
```

If I try this

```
$this->db->where_in( '(userId, customer_id)', array( array(10,1809), array(10,1809), array(45,210) ));
$this->db->delete('table');
die(var_dump($this->db->last_query()));
```

I get this, which is not correct, of course:

```
DELETE FROM `table`
WHERE (userId, customer_id) IN(Array, Array, Array)
```

Comment: Does the table have a primary key from which you are trying delete the records??

Comment: If yes then try deleting the records using IN keyword with a primary key of that table. It will work.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810609/codeigniter-active-record-delete-multiple-records-at-once

Comment: @BeingprabhU these two are primary keys: userId and customer_id

Comment: combination of primary keys is it??

Comment: If a combination of primary keys then I'm not sure if it is possible. You can better have a primary key in the table which will be easy to delete

Comment: yes, it's a combination of primary keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get the associated array values into single array then passit into query

```
$assoicative_array = array(array(10,20,30));
    $ids=array();
    foreach($assoicative_array as $key =>$value ){
        $ids[]=$value;
    }
    $this->db->where_in('userId',$ids);
    $this->db->where_in('customer_id',$ids);
    $this->db->delete('table');
    die(var_dump($this->db->last_query()));
```

Comment: he can check $ids = array_unique($ids); to overcome it

Comment: @BeingprabhU I can delete these records, it's- ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION

Comment: @BeingprabhU yes, there may be multiple records with the same userId, but there may not be records with same userId AND customer_id

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it works:

```
foreach ( $data as $row )
{
    $userIds[] = $row['userId'];
    $customerIds[] = $row['customerId'];
}

$this->db->where_in('userId', $userIds);
$this->db->where_in('customer_id', $customerIds);
$this->db->delete('table');
```

this deletes the rows and generated query is:

```
DELETE FROM `table`
WHERE `userId` IN('10', '11', '54')
AND `customer_id` IN('1809', '1904', '201')
```

Comment: @elango, Please edit your answer to store the values in different variables.